# How to get Place ID of city from Latitude/Longitude using Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation, facebook-fql

I need to find the Facebook place for the **city** for many lat/long points. The actual points refer to personal addresses, so there are no exact place ID's to look for as in the case of a business.

For testing, I was looking for the town of [Red Feather Lakes, CO.](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Red-Feather-Lakes-Colorado/105606916140270)

- The graph search function will return a lot of places, but does not return cities [Example](https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=40.8078,-105.579&distance=10000&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAKkFoX1ewvvYvkc8vhCwMGtaN1hCXpOvzQ0XxKkXpg1repWE9QnnGF8HYjsGvWtoAIk0GBzp6gCHvzxX9YRY3EalogZDZD)
- Raw FQL does not let you search by lat/long, and has no concept of "nearby" anyway. [Example](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20latitude=40.801985%20AND%20longitude=-105.593719&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAKkFoX1ewvvYvkc8vhCwMGtaN1hCXpOvzQ0XxKkXpg1repWE9QnnGF8HYjsGvWtoAIk0GBzp6gCHvzxX9YRY3EalogZDZD)
- An FQL query by ID reveals that there is an least a "Display Subtext" field which indicates that object is a city. [Example](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20page_id=105606916140270&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAKkFoX1ewvvYvkc8vhCwMGtaN1hCXpOvzQ0XxKkXpg1repWE9QnnGF8HYjsGvWtoAIk0GBzp6gCHvzxX9YRY3EalogZDZD)

Thanks for any help. I have over 80 years of dated and geotagged photos of my dad that he would love to see on his timeline!

**EDIT**

Cities are not in the `place` table, they are only in the `page` table.
There is an undocumented `distance()` FQL function, but it only works in the `place` table. (Via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250368/facebook-fql-get-checkins-within-range/8118424).)

This works:

```
SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude, display_subtext 
FROM place 
WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "40.801985", "-105.593719") < 50000
```

But this gives an error "distance is not valid in table page":

```
SELECT page_id,name,description,type,location 
FROM page 
WHERE distance(
  location.latitude,location.longitude,
  "40.801985", "-105.593719") < 50000
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a glorious hack, but this code works. The trick is to make two queries. First we look for places near our point. This returns a lot of business places. We then take the **city** of one of these places, and use this to look in the `page` table for that city's page. There seems to be a standard naming conventions for cities, but different for US and non-US cities.

Some small cities have various spellings in the `place` table, so the code loops through the returned places until it finds a match in the `page` table.

```
$fb_token = 'YOUR_TOKEN';

// Red Feather Lakes, Colorado
$lat = '40.8078';
$long = '-105.579';
// Karlsruhe, Germany
$lat = '49.037868';
$long = '8.350124';

$states_arr  = array('AL'=>"Alabama",'AK'=>"Alaska",'AZ'=>"Arizona",'AR'=>"Arkansas",'CA'=>"California",'CO'=>"Colorado",'CT'=>"Connecticut",'DE'=>"Delaware",'FL'=>"Florida",'GA'=>"Georgia",'HI'=>"Hawaii",'ID'=>"Idaho",'IL'=>"Illinois", 'IN'=>"Indiana", 'IA'=>"Iowa",  'KS'=>"Kansas",'KY'=>"Kentucky",'LA'=>"Louisiana",'ME'=>"Maine",'MD'=>"Maryland", 'MA'=>"Massachusetts",'MI'=>"Michigan",'MN'=>"Minnesota",'MS'=>"Mississippi",'MO'=>"Missouri",'MT'=>"Montana",'NE'=>"Nebraska",'NV'=>"Nevada",'NH'=>"New Hampshire",'NJ'=>"New Jersey",'NM'=>"New Mexico",'NY'=>"New York",'NC'=>"North Carolina",'ND'=>"North Dakota",'OH'=>"Ohio",'OK'=>"Oklahoma", 'OR'=>"Oregon",'PA'=>"Pennsylvania",'RI'=>"Rhode Island",'SC'=>"South Carolina",'SD'=>"South Dakota",'TN'=>"Tennessee",'TX'=>"Texas",'UT'=>"Utah",'VT'=>"Vermont",'VA'=>"Virginia",'WA'=>"Washington",'DC'=>"Washington D.C.",'WV'=>"West Virginia",'WI'=>"Wisconsin",'WY'=>"Wyoming");

$place_search = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=' . $lat . ',' . $long . '&distance=10000&access_token=' . $fb_token));
foreach($place_search->data as $result) {
  if ($result->location->city) {
    $city = $result->location->city;
    $state = $result->location->state;
    $country = $result->location->country;
    if ($country=='United States') {
      $city_name = $city . ', ' . $states_arr[$state]; // e.g. 'Chicago, Illinois'
    }
    else {
      $city_name = $city . ', ' . $country; // e.g. 'Rome, Italy'
    }
    $fql = 'SELECT name,page_id,name,description,type,location FROM page WHERE type="CITY" and name="' .$city_name. '"';
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . rawurlencode($fql) . '&access_token=' . $fb_token));
    if (count($result->data)>0) {
      // We found it!
      print_r($result);
      break;
    }
    else {
      // No luck, try the next place
      print ("Couldn't find " . $city_name . "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution worked for me when looking for a page for the closest city to the specified latitude/longitude. For some reason LIMIT 1 didn't return the closest city so I bumped up the limit and then took the first result.

```
SELECT page_id
FROM place
WHERE is_city and distance(latitude, longitude, "<latitude>", "<longitude>") < 100000
ORDER BY distance(latitude, longitude, "<latitude>", "<longitude>")
LIMIT 20
```