# What is the parameter "distance" when using search fql?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

What does "distance" refer to? Amount of miles? Radius? I can't find any documentation on it. What's the maximum limit FB will allow us to grab?

```
$nearby = $facebook->api('/search?type=place&center='.$_GET['lat'].','.$_GET['lon'].'&distance=1000&limit=200');
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250368/facebook-fql-get-checkins-within-range/8118424#8118424, `distance` is an undocumented function, limited to 50km, and doesn't work very well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distance refers to the radius with respect to the latitude and longitude of the location in meters. As mentioned by [Chris](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9501449/what-is-the-parameter-distance-when-using-search-fql#comment12030812_9501449), the maximum is 50,000 m.