# What units are the Facebook search distance parameter in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

Facebook allows a distance parameter for their search like

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

They don't say what units this is in. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distance is messured in meters (source: [Using Actions - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/)):

> place - Page ID of the place where the action took place. You can
>   search for the Place ID using our Graph API.
>
> - Specify type=place
> - Specify q as query parameter
> - Optional distance (in meters)

But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501449/what-is-the-parameter-distance-when-using-search-fql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250368/facebook-fql-get-checkins-within-range/8118424#8118424), this is not very accurate and limited to 50km.

Comment: That's the exact same limit as the Google Place API, makes sense.

Comment: Can we also search group members by distance?