# How to search near by places in facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search near places on `Facebook` using `Graph Api`.

```
        double lat = 23.454554,lon=76.554545;
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("type", "place");
        params.putString("center", lat + "," + lon);
        params.putString("distance", "5000");
        params.putString("limit", "40");

        mFacebookRunner.request("search", params,
                new SearchPlaces());
```

I am able to get 20 results even if i increase distance to 10,000 meters it provides 20 results only.i want to retrieve 40 search result..

**Edit :**

https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=60&type=place&center=23.032852,72.637334&distance=10000&access_token=my_access_token

I am able to get almost 50 search results, but first option don't give more than 20 results.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get the search results near 40 but not exact 40..

```
    double lat = 23.454554,lon=76.554545;
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("type", "place");
    params.putString("center", lat + "," + lon);
    params.putString("distance", "5000");
    params.putString("limit", "40");

    mFacebookRunner.request("search", params,
            new SearchPlaces());
```

Log cat showed only 20 results(Due to its limitation) ,but when i checked the length of array it came near 40.. It works to search places..

Answer (score 0):

You have an undocumented method distance() you can use as described here:

[Facebook FQL: Get checkins within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250368/facebook-fql-get-checkins-within-range)