# Facebook SDK & iOS: Loop to run through nearby places

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm new to the Facebook SDK, and am trying to setup a loop to run-through 10 nearby places presented in the FBPlacePickerViewController, then fetch and store the longitude and latitude in an array. Here is an example of the view:
[image]

I've discovered that I can fetch and store the long and lat like so:

```
- (void)facebookPlaces {
 FBPlacePickerViewController *placePickerController = [[FBPlacePickerViewController alloc] init];
    placePickerController.title = @"Nearby Places";
NSString *placeName = placePickerController.selection.name;
 if (!placeName) {
             placeName = @"<No Place Selected>";
         }
         // This grabs the long and lat of each place selected:
         NSString *firstLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", placePickerController.locationCoordinate.latitude];
         NSLog(@"First Lat: %@", firstLat);
         NSString *firstLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", placePickerController.locationCoordinate.longitude];
         NSLog(@"First Long: %@", firstLong);
}
```

Now, I would like to setup a loop to programatically select 10 of the nearest places, then store the long and lats in an array. I have two issues: First, I'm unsure of how to programmatically select / fetch 10 places. I can manually launch the app, launch this view, tap on **only one** of them, then collect the info only when "Done" is tapped. I would love to select 10 at once through code alone. Does anyone know how to create a loop like this? Or if there is a better method? I'm very new to code.

**EDIT:** It is looking like FQL is the best way to fetch the long and lat of the 10 nearest places. This is the code I have written so far (Thanks for all the help Paulw11). The only issue is I'm running into "Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)". This is how my code looks:

```
- (void)facebookPlaces {

    NSString *query =
    @"SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, 37.75377496892, -122.42077080676) < 500 limit 10";
    // Set up the query parameter
    NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:queryParam
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                              } else {
                                  NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                              }
                          }];
}
```

Comment: You need " around the numbers as they are literals - use `NSString *query =
    @"SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, \"37.75377496892\", \"-122.42077080676\") < 500 limit 10"`  Obviously once you are done testing you will use something `stringWithFormat` to insert your actual location from CoreLocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than directly accessing `placePickerController.selection.name` you should implement the [`FBPlacePickerDelegate`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBPlacePickerDelegate/) protocol in your class.  You can then access the selected place in  your `placePickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:` method.

The `FBPlacePickerDelegate` protocol also defines a method   `placePickerViewController:shouldIncludePlace:` which is called for each place that will be added to the picker - you could use this method to capture the places in an array.

However, based on the second part of your question, I suspect that what you *really* want to do is retrieve nearby places *without* the user interface.  To do this you need to query the Facebook [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph)  The answer to this question [Facebook FQL: Get checkins within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250368/facebook-fql-get-checkins-within-range) shows an FQL query using the distance() function - you should be able to use that as a starting point.

You can use an FQL query like `SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "37.75377496892", "-122.42077080676") < 500 limit 10` to retrieve 10 places within 500 meters of the specified latitude and longitude.

You can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me?fields=id,name) to experiment with your FQL queries.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the great suggestions. I have little to no experience with queries, do you know how I could query the long and lat of the ten nearest places? I'm doing some research now but it is going over my head, I think I need to get a few tutorials on queries.